# Windows 10 search result shows no icon for Store apps?

Tags: windows-10, icons, start-menu, windows-search

After several automated updates since installation, my windows start menu search is broken. It couldn't show icons for any Windows 10 apps, but for regular legacy program the icon is displayed properly? Any possible way to fix this?

[image: broken icon]

EDIT: Automated suggestion suggest me [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1247025/icons-not-showing-in-windows-10-search) Q&A, but the solution there doesn't solve my problem. I had the preset to "best appearance", so the checkbox mentioned there already checked, along with everything else. So please don't blindly mark it as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

It could be caused by Windows Store cache may be damaged.

1. To reset the Windows Store cache, open the Sytem32 folder and look for the WSReset.exe.  Right-click on it and select Run as administrator.
2. Use a bat file in the link below to rebuild the icon cache 
   https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5645-rebuild-icon-cache-windows-10-a.html
3. Signing out from and signing back in to the Store App

Comment: I ran the bat file and rebooted, but then how do I sign out from Store app? There is no sign out button anywhere I can found.

Comment: Hi, Open the Store app. Once the Store app is launched, tap or click your Microsoft account picture. Then you could sign out. Also I was wondering if this. bat file is invalid?

Comment: Alright, I managed to logout. Actually, ran the bat file, restart, then signout from Store, restart, then signin. Problem still there. Tried it again, ran the bat file, restore the *.ico reg from https://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/8486-default-file-associations-restore-windows-8-a.html, linked from the link you mentioned on step 2, reboot, sign out from store, then sign in again. Unfortunately, the problem is still there.

Comment: Oh, well. I consider that if it is related to the user profile. Create a new user account to check.
Meanwhile, try to use command “sfc /scannow” repair the system files

Comment: sfc reports it "did not find any integrity violations.". That's the thing, in another user account the icon works fine.

Comment: @Nur Did you find a solution for this? I'm also having the same problem and can't find a way to fix this stupid bug... A new user account fixes the problem, but that's a workaround, not a fix :/

Comment: Nope. I'd just accept that Windows 10 is a broken product, there's just too many stupid silly bugs and problem, "attention to details" definitely not its strong point. Either that, or use alternatives.