# Icons in windows Start Menu / Search are gone and replaced with another app

Tags: windows-10, icons, windows-search

When I open Start Menu, I can scroll through the apps and the icons are fine.

[image]

However, when I start typing (searching), many of the icons get replaced with IrfanView.

[image]

Uninstalling IrfanView did not help.
Restoring the Windows icon cache did not help too.

How to fix this?

Comment: Make a new, test, Windows User Account and Profile.  Log into the new account and see if the Start Menu works properly.

Comment: The methods you have tried do not work with UWP apps. Try this: Install IrfanView, do *Options > Check ALL extensions > OK*. Exit IrfanView and relaunch and do *Options > Uncheck ALL extensions > OK*.

Comment: @John The other account's icons are fine when searching.

Comment: @harrymc It didn't help. I also tried doing it as admin.

Comment: Try this: Open an elevated PowerShell and enter this command: `Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}`.

Comment: @harrymc It does something, says "Deployment operation progress: C:\Program Files\...", but below it it sometimes writes an error "Add-AppxPackage : Cannot find path 'C:\AppXManifest.xml' because it does not exist.", or "Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x..." ... because ... "driver could not be found", "higher version is already installed", "resource currently in use" or "package is currently paused". etc.

Comment: That's another problem. The question is whether this helped, if not - reboot and check again.

Comment: @harrymc Restarted, it didn't help. And now I get many error popups like "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\...\....exe The parameter is incorrect"

Thank you for your effort, I don't want to bother you too much. I will try to do more research on internet.

Comment: Something screwed up your setup. Try to test Windows integrity by running [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: @harrymc Both commands finished within minutes successfully. sfc didn't find any integrity violations.

Comment: In this case, I have to suggest to [Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: @harrymc I managed to fix it by following this answer https://superuser.com/a/1538058/99602. Turns out, the issue is caused by Google Drive File Stream - DriveFS Thumbnail Provider, which is set as a Thumbnail provider for `.png` files in registry. Removing it fixed it.