# Windows 10 Start Menu App Icons Replaced by Picture Icons

Tags: windows, windows-10, icons

So I recently noticed a strange problem with Windows 10's default apps (so the ones that *come* with windows 10, not the ones you set). Most apps which come with Windows 10's icons in Windows Search have been replaced with a "blank" icon. (See below)
[image: 1]

Strangely it doesn't happen with other apps (like office apps) but only occurs with the apps which come with the operating system.

**Another Example**
[image: Second Example]

The only 3rd party app this bug affects is the Sophos Home Premium Antivirus (although this issue happened before I installed the Antivirus)
[image: sophos issue]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  So far the answers provided have done nothing.  Interestingly, it's only if I search: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExJ9J.png  If I find the app manually, it has the correct icon: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5R8eY.png

Comment: I want to add that it's not every app that was installed via Store, but only affects Store apps.  So far I've found (non-MS): LastPass, Speedtest, Lyft, Uber, Trello.  "BarCode Read It" has the right background color for some reason.

Comment: @undrline-ReinstateMonica: Which version of Windows 10? Have you tried to repeair the apps in an elevated PowerShell with: `Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}`

Comment: I did the windows GUI Repair (one I tried the Reset), but that thing has never ever fixed any problem, only just deleted app data, lol.  winver: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKYGH.png

Comment: @harrymc forgot to tag you above.  I'm sorry I don't know PowerShell well enough to adapt that command to my needs.  Could you give an example with the Windows default Photos app?

Comment: @undrline-ReinstateMonica: The above command reinstalls all the apps that are installed from the Microsoft Store. What you need to do is to open an elevated PowerShell session and paste this command.

Comment: Hi, this is OP. I kind of forgot about this question (sorry!), and have since moved on to Linux. However, I won't close/delete this question, as a few of you appear to have the same issue. I didn't really expect this much attention! Thank you to everyone who has answered or tried to help. :)

Comment: @harrymc `Missing opening '(' after keyword 'foreach'.` should it be parenthesis instead of curly brackets?

Comment: Sorry, the command is missing a part. It should be: `Get-AppXPackage | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}`.

Comment: @undrline-ReinstateMonica: Did it help?

Comment: Could this help? https://superuser.com/questions/1247025/icons-not-showing-in-windows-10-search

Comment: @harrymc unfortunately, it did not.  Some failed because they were in use, but none of those packages were the ones that had issues anyway.

Comment: @User552853 That looks like the same issue, but none of the fixes worked: changing scale, uninstall google sync and changing scale, or checking to save taskbar thumbnails and rebooting.

Comment: Try deleted all the files present in the location C:\Users\<username of the main account>\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.Search_cw5n1h2txyewy\Settings
Reins @undrline-ReinstateMonica

Comment: @undrline-ReinstateMonica and then restart your computer as well

Answer (score 1):

For this answer you'll need another Admin user different from the user experiencing this issue. :

1. Log into your other admin account. Open registry, Make a new `string value` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer`
2. Name it `MaxCachedIcons`, type the value as `2048`
3. Delete the file `C:\Users\<User Name>\AppData\Local\IconCache.db` where the "username" is the user facing problems.

There is a workaround if you don't have/don't want to make another user, however it might work, or might not. Do the 1 & 2 steps as it is. Then for step three, do it in the style you did [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1579967/windows-10-default-apps-icon-replaced-by-blank-picture-icon#comment2630944_1579968), **Two times**, ie, once more after it is rebuilt, after logging off and on.

Comment: It didn't work, but it did bring up a couple of things.  I can't speak for the OP, obviously. 1) I'm using an MS account, and 2) I'm also using a hybrid environment with an SSD (C:) for most system stuff and a mechanical drive (D:) for data ... including the Users directory.  I can't remember if I set the Users folder up as a directory junction or symbolic link, but I do know it confuses some installers.  For instance, LibreOffice refuses to install saying it can't find its own installation files.

Comment: My answer was derived from the solution of a [similar bug](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/icons-are-changed-unexpectedly-in-windows-2c426994-1b80-6e3a-06be-55fc3cf9d17d) that existed in windows 7. Your issue sure is quite interesting though. I'll keep researching and edit it into my answer whenever I find a solution

Comment: @undrline-ReinstateMonica, Two observations I did, the icons of the apps are replaced by the icons displayed over files — the folded triangle on the top-right corner is meant to mean "file". Second, the "file" icon is displayed "over" the icon of the app. For eg, One Note's icon + Icons of Files which are images = https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJ3fR.png

Comment: @undrline-ReinstateMonica, have you tried `sfc /scannow` ?

Comment: @Saaransh_Garg ofc.  no dice.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can happen for any kind of third party handler of .png icons. Open regedit as Administrator and go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.png\shellex` then remove any GUID looking subkey there.

Comment: I found the .png "folder" but couldn't locate shellex inside. There were only 2 subfolders called `PersistentHandler` and `OpenWithProgids`

Comment: I did have a key there but removing it changed nothing and I still have the default icon (GIMP in my case): https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExJ9J.png

Comment: @Wasif were right. After removing the key, just do two more steps. First restart `explorer.exe`  then change the scaling back and forth between 100/125/175%. Following answer with more clear instructions helped me to resolve the same issue. https://superuser.com/a/1441161/979451

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall all the Microsoft Store apps by in an elevated
PowerShell session running the following command:

```
Get-AppXPackage | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

Reboot after running the command.

Comment: Thank you for making it a full-fledged answer; maybe it'll help someone else even though it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

## Attempt 1

Open Command Prompt (`cmd.exe`) then run:

`del /a /f "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\IconCache.db"`

```
cd /d "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer"
attrib -h iconcache*.db
del /f iconcache*.db
y
```

Reboot your PC, if it didn't worked continue to another attempt

## Attempt 2

Open command prompt (`cmd.exe`) as administrator

run the following commands:

```
dism /online /cleanup-image /checkhealth
dism /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth
dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth

sfc /scannow
```

Then reboot your PC and check if it worked. If not, continue to another attempt.

## Attempt 3

Try configuring your display settings to recommended by windows
Right-click on desktop and click display settings. Then change scaling, display, refresh rate, etc. to recommended.

Reboot and check if it worked. If not, go to another step.

## Attempt 4

**(skip this step if you do not have Google Drive installed)**

Sometimes syncing files by google drive might cause Icons to display improperly. So, to fix this issue, Open Task Manager, Go to Startup tab, then right click on Google Drive then disable.

Reboot and check if it worked.

## And last

Wait... there are many other things you can try, if none of these worked, create a new user account and move your files into it.

Comment: -1 — Don't see how Attempt 3 and Attempt 4 Could help.

Comment: Also, note that if `dism /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth` reports no problem, doing `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` is unnecessary

Comment: @SaaranshGarg people have reported that it does help for some reason; it's not necessary to downvote.  everything above was already mentioned/linked in various comments and has been tried.  None of them worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still arriving on this page (I know I did), the solution that worked for me was what @dheerendra wrote in one of the comments, and presented in more detail here:

[Some Windows 10 UWP icons not displaying on search, or in settings](https://superuser.com/questions/1319157/some-windows-10-uwp-icons-not-displaying-on-search-or-in-settings/1441161#1441161)

You do **not** need to change permissions on that Registry key, most probably you don't even have to delete the GUIDs or touch the registry at all. As others have reported in the comments below, the thing that finally seems to do it, is changing the display scale (e.g. from 100% to 125%, to 150%, etc.) a few times, and this seems to rebuild the icon cache properly. ‍♂️